# HTML5 canvas redraw on parameter change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, coffeescript

I have this code, running every time when one of parameners (c) is changed. (It's some kind of seamless texture generator, for better understanding what I want to get):

```
class drawPreview 
    constructor: (c) ->
        pic = new Image()
        pic.src = $("#sample_file").attr('src')
        canvas = document.getElementById("preview_canvas")
        context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        img_w = $("#sample_file").attr('width')
        img_h = $("#sample_file").attr('height')
        tiles = Math.floor(img_w / c.w) + 1
        for i in [0..tiles]
            console.log('t')
            context.width = context.width
            context.drawImage(pic, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, c.w*i, 0, c.w, c.h)
```

This works good in Firefox (with some lagging). But in Chrome it freezes for some time and unfreezes same way. Is there any way to do it more sensible to user's actions?

Comment: There is a fair amount of computation that could be moved out of that.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to solve this task? Except flash. Only HTML5 way needed

Answer (score 0):

if only parameter changing is 'C' then move all the code outside of the this block.

move the below code out it should be called once.

```
        pic = new Image()
        pic.src = $("#sample_file").attr('src')
        canvas = document.getElementById("preview_canvas")
        context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        img_w = $("#sample_file").attr('width')
        img_h = $("#sample_file").attr('height')
```

The above operations may be costly.

Comment: Well, I've found out what is going on. Reason is hardware acceleration. If I turn it off, lags are gone. So, next question will be - is there any way to turn it off from javascript? I guess than no. And this is become a problem... :(